# Rename files in the folder using matlab

Tags: matlab

This is a two part questions.

1. I have a bunch of pdf file which has names like:

   First_2000_ This is the first file.pdf

   Second_2010_ second file.pdf

   Thd_1987_Third file.pdf

   There are huge number of files which has name format like this (alphabets_year_[sometimes space will be there or will not be there]fairly long title with spaces.pdf). Now I want to rename all in such a fashion where there is no space between year and title (e.g. First_2000_This is the first file.pdf; Second_2010_second file.pdf).
   I have written the code taking clue from https://in.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/answers/338822-rename-files-using-matlab. But the code that I have written clear all the space between them:

```
clear; clc;
folder_name = 'C:\Users\SREERAJ\Desktop\New folder';
dir_infrmatn = dir( fullfile(folder_name, '*.pdf') );
prvs_name = {dir_infrmatn.name};
reduntant = cellfun(@isempty, regexp(prvs_name, '^[A-Z][^_].*') );
prvs_name(reduntant) = [];
regexprep(prvs_name, '\s', '$0')
   for k = 1 : length(prvs_name)
      movefile( fullfile(folder_name, prvs_name{k}), fullfile(folder_name, newnames{k}) );
   end
```

2. Second set of files has the format

   2018-04-19 This is the first file.pdf

   19190829Second file.pdf

   This set of files have to converted into format of “20180419This is the first file.pdf” i.e. 
   “yearmonthdayName.pdf” (name can have spaces between, e.g. 20180419This is the first file.pdf).

How to accomplish both of this tasks?

Comment: Seeing that your original file names seem way too inconsistent for a proper pattern recognition, I would rather go this route: (i) make a table with the list of all your old filename, (ii) Sort the table (automatically and/or manually), until you are sure the files are in the right order. (iii) Run a script which generate a consistent file numbering and apply the script to your files, following the index obtained in step (ii).

Comment: next time you ask a question on stackoverflow, you may want to provide a (complete) runnable code snippet with data to help people get started more easily

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is more a regex problem than a MATLAB problem. Here is a working example for both of your tasks:

```
filenames1 = {
    'First_2000_ This is the first file.pdf'
    'Second_2010_ second file.pdf'
    'Thd_1987_Third file.pdf'
};

fun1 = @(x) regexprep(x, '^(.+\d{4})_ (.+)$', '$1_$2');
newfilenames1 = cellfun(fun1, filenames1, 'UniformOutput', false);

filenames2 = {
    '2018-04-19 This is the first file.pdf'
    '19190829Second file.pdf'
};

fun2 = @(x) regexprep(x, '^(\d{4})-(\d{2})-(\d{2}) (.+)$', '$1$2$3$4');
newfilenames2 = cellfun(fun2, filenames2, 'UniformOutput', false);
```

Output:

```
newfilenames1 =

  3×1 cell array

    {'First_2000_This is the first file.pdf'}
    {'Second_2010_second file.pdf'          }
    {'Thd_1987_Third file.pdf'              }

newfilenames2 =

  2×1 cell array

    {'20180419This is the first file.pdf'}
    {'19190829Second file.pdf'           }
```

If you need to do this a lot, you may want to really dig into regex and understand these weird expressions.

P.S. Since these renaming jobs do not use any numerical calculation at all, you might consider use a general purpose script language (like Python) unless you are limited to MATLAB. In my personal experience, Python offers simpler and more powerful string manipulation operations, and I see a much better performance in renaming a large number of files.

Comment: This is a good answer. I think this method is simple and efficient enough as is unless a huge number of files are to be renamed.

Comment: Thanks @Zhe, but a small issue: for the 1st in the loop, if i give this command, 
`for k = 1 : length(prvs_name)
       movefile( fullfile(folder_name, prvs_name{k}), fullfile(folder_name, newfilenames1{k}) );
end`
files names are changed in same folder.
But for 2nd, if this is written inside loop:
`for k = 1 : length(prvs_name)
      movefile( fullfile(folder_name, prvs_name{k}), fullfile(folder_name, newfilenames2{k}) );
   end`
error comes
Error using movefile. Cannot copy or move a file or directory onto itself.
I got around by giving other folder path. But, why it's happening?

Comment: @sreerajt The error message literally explains what is going on -- you cannot do something like `movefile('1.pdf', '1.pdf')`, since the source and destination is same. Moving to another folder works, and there are many other ways to do this, the easiest of which is to use an additional `if` in your loop (if filenames are same, do not do the `movefile` operation)

Comment: I understood the error message. But my question is why is it showing on the second, but why not one first, even-though both have same command.

Comment: @sreerajt sorry I misunderstood your question. I do not know, as this should not happen. Can you try running the program again? Since the files are already renamed, the first should throw an error message.

Comment: @Zhe thanks once again for the speedy comment. I tried, but same error. Maybe I will ponder over it..

Comment: @Zhe You may be interested in this weblink: https://in.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/answers/526072-files-getting-moved-to-another-folder-while-renaming-using-regexp-and-movefile-command